# Stepping Through JavaScript Code Evaluated by ScriptEngine

Tags: java, javascript, multithreading, scriptengine

I have a desktop Java application that essentially is meant to be a dispatcher for a number of threads.  Each thread is responsible for reading a JavaScript file and interpreting/evaluating the JavaScript code.  The JavaScript scripts complex tasks that run indefinitely, controlling Java objects exposed by the parent Java application.

I have no problem with any of this.  I create a thread which reads the appropriate JavaScript file, then evaluates it.  Something like:

```
public class TaskThread extends Thread {
    ...
    public void run() {
        String theScriptCode = ReadMyJavascriptFileIntoAString("somescript.js");
        ScriptEngineManager engineManager = new ScriptEngineManager();
        engine = engineManager.getEngineByName("nashorn");
        scriptableObject = new MyScriptableObjectClass();
        engine.put("scriptableObject", scriptableObject);
        engine.eval(theScriptCode);
    }
    ...
}
```

The somescript.js file might contain something like:

```
while (!isAFullMoon()) {
    scriptableObject.doSomething();
    scriptableObject.doSomethingElse();
}
```

Therefore, the line:

```
engine.eval(theScriptCode);
```

... could very well run for a very long time.

What I need is some way for my TaskThread object to be notified every time a new expression/function is evaluated in theScriptCode.  This is necessary because, since engine.eval(theScriptCode) will be running for a long time, I want the ScriptEngine to yield periodically.

I could do this by making the TaskThread object visible to the instance of MyScriptableObjectClass().  Something like:

```
        ...
        scriptableObject = new MyScriptableObjectClass(this);
        engine.put("scriptableObject", scriptableObject);
        ...
```

Then, in the definition of MyScriptableObjectClass:

```
public class MyScriptableObjectClass {
    private TaskThread parentThread;

    public MyScriptableObjectClass(TaskThread t) {
        this.parentThread = t;
    }

    public void doSomething() {
        // do something
        parentThread.yield();
        ...
    }

    public void doSomethingElse() {
        // do something else
        parentThread.yield();
        ...
    }
```

Seems like there must be a more elegant way to do this - especially since this would only allow me to yield during calls to methods of Java objects.  There may be significant periods of time that JavaScript is executing without making a call to any Java object members.

What I would like is to be able to do something like add a listener to the ScriptEngine object to fire each time a new expression is evaluated.  Seems like this should be pretty straight forward, but I've been spinning my wheels on this for days.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Such "instrumentation" of (nashorn compiled) script is not supported by nashorn. You can instantiate a Timer or spawn a separate thread from script -- and the timer callback or thread's run can have script that "pings" by making a Java call.

Comment: Thanks for the thoughts.  I've been thinking sort of along these lines.  This raises another question, but it sort of redefines the problem for me.  So, I'll ask a different question.